# How to compare different actions done by different people?

Tags: translation

For example, consider the following English phrase:

> Speaking Japanese is much harder for me than speaking English is for you.

How would one put this in Japanese? Would...

> 私が日本語で話すことは、貴方が英語で話すことより、難しいです。

... work?

What would be the natural way to express it?

Comment: I think it is correct. Currently cannot think of a better way to say it.

Comment: if you want many versions you could ask this question on http://esaura.cc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example works. Having a comma after `より` is slightly unnatural, though. You can also use `にとって`:

> 私にとって、日本語で話すことは、貴方が英語で話すことより難しいです。